# Стандарт допустимых значения href

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, стандарт

Помимо абсолютного или относительного пути к ресурсам в `<a href="smth">...</a>` могут быть еще и специальные ссылки: выполнить джаваскрипт, отправить письмо, запустить программу и т.д. Где можно почитать стандарт на такие ссылки?

Comment: [Здесь](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/)

Answer (score 1):

В ссылки можно JS ставить например есть JavaScript функция `function` то с помощью ссылки мы можем ее вызвать

```
href="javascript:function();"
```

Так например можно сделать вызов модального окна.
Насчет письма есть такая штука

```
href="mailto:info@mail.com"
```

Нажав на такую ссылку браузер предложит отправить письмо по данному адресу (не Google Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прочитать про стандарты следует обратиться к референсу. Так как HTML 4.01 ещё не умер, а html5 ещё не родился полностью, следует использовать [референс от 4.01 для ссылок (EN)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

> A link has two ends -- called anchors -- and a direction. The link starts at the "source" anchor and points to the "destination" anchor, which may be any Web resource (e.g., an image, a video clip, a sound bite, a program, an HTML document, an element within an HTML document, etc.).

---

> Всем ссылкам присущи по 2 якоря (точки) и направление. Ссылка ведёт из начальной точки в конечную, которая может быть веб-ресурсом (например изображением, видео, звуком, программой, HTML-документом, элементом в таком документе и пр. ...)